# Why using label is recommended together with function parameter

Tags: objective-c

I was wondering, what is real benifit, to have label together with function parameter. As far as I know, the following way

**Not recommended**

```
-(void) insertObject:(id)anObject:(unsigned int)index
```

**Recommended**

```
-(void) insertObject:(id)anObject atIndex:(unsigned int)index
```

Besides :

1. Enable function overloading, what else?

Comment: So you know what the second argument is for? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because using the parameter labels makes the function call read somewhat more like an English sentence rather than a magic incantation.

Comment: Cheers on this one bro! I got a really big laugh. And the answer completely makes sense.

Answer (score 6):

This doesn't enable function overloading. Obj-C doesn't have function overloading. What it does is name the method correctly. Your first method is named `-insertObject::` and the second is named `-insertObject:atIndex:`. While both technically work, the former is considered extremely bad form, especially if you add even more parameters, e.g. `-doSomething::::`.

One of the oft-cited benefits of Obj-C is the method naming allows you to understand what code is doing by reading it without having to look at documentation. For example, if I have

```
[self initWithName:@"foo" andAge:13]
```

it's immediately obvious what the parameters are, but if I had

```
[self init:@"foo" :13]
```

then it's not obvious at all what these parameters are supposed to represent.

It also helps when you have similarly-named methods. For example, NSKeyValueCoding defines both `-setValue:forKey:` and `-setValue:forUndefinedKey:`. Quite obviously, if it had been named `-setValue::`, then there would be a collision here.